# Is there a way to limit traffic to just SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, hot-spot

I am going to be using my phone as a mobile hotspot so I can SSH from my laptop into my home server, as the phone is my only available data currently. Is there a way to limit the connections on the laptop to only run the ssh connection so I don't accidentally crush my data plan with background traffic.

So my connection is as follows:

Laptop running Xubuntu 14.04 
->
Moto G connected on T-Mobile
->
Home Server

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`iptables`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) rules like so:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT  -j REJECT
```

This blocks all in and out traffic except for TCP connections to port 22 (usually SSH). Non-standard SSH ports are also filtered. DNS is also filtered, so you might want to allow DNS ports (usually 53, IIRC).

`iptables` is not aware of the content of the traffic, as far as I know, so you cannot make it filter SSH traffic irrespective of ports.